# Data XML provider loading SOA Mortality tables

Tags: xml, f#, type-providers, f#-data

I cannot seem to load the mortality data form the xml files hosted on the SOA website at http://mort.soa.org/

```
#r "../packages/FSharp.Data.1.1.10/lib/net40/FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
open FSharp.Data
type mortab = XmlProvider<"http://mort.soa.org/data/t1.xml">

let mtab = mortab.Load("http://mort.soa.org/data/t1.xml")

let rates = mtab.Table.Values.Axis
```

It does not seem to be possible to access data within the Axis element. An option to use a method GetIes is returned from intellisense, and this reports an error 'The Name of a provided type was null or empty'.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try again with 2.0 prerelease? I just tested your snippet and it worked

Comment: That's great. "mtab.Table.Values.Axis.GetIes()" now generates an array of elements and you can use "rate.Y" to get the t Attribute and use "rate.Value" to get the decimal rate.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had issues getting exactly what I want out of F# Data's XML TypeProvider. For ad-hoc work though it normally gets me close. Since the TypeProvider also gives you the `XElement` at each node you can always use the TypeProvider to get you almost there and just navigate the `XElement` and `XAttributes` to get you the rest of the way.

```fs
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.1.1.10\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"

open FSharp.Data
open System.Linq
open System.Xml.Linq
type mortab = XmlProvider<"http://mort.soa.org/data/t1.xml">
let xname (tag:string) = XName.Get(tag)
let mtab = mortab.Load("http://mort.soa.org/data/t1.xml")

let rates = 
    mtab.Table.Values.Axis.XElement.Elements(xname "Y")
    |> Seq.map (fun e -> e.Attribute(xname "t").Value |> int, e.Value |> float)
    |> Seq.toArray
```